# extract data point from tiff picture

Tags: c#, tiff

I did some google seraches but could not find an answer. Is it possible to extract data points from a tiff image? If it is a vector type format it should be possible I reckon ... I am a fairly good programmer (C# preferably). Thanks.

Christian[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "data"? If you mean embedded EXIF, or retrieving an image from the TIFF, then yes.

Comment: not sure what I mean. I included the image. No idea what EXIF means ... I suppose that might be the embedded data?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong or correct the question if I'm right: you don't want to extract data from a tiff picture, what you want to do is extract the _data points_ from _this_ tiff picture, right?

Comment: Yes you are right - sorry if my question was not clear. I have edited it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab and some code called grabit seem to help. Not sure whether there are better ways but that helped so far:

[File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit)

The data points are red. Maybe that also clarifies what I mean by data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not clearly for me what is "data" in your case. But hope `TIFF File format specification` will help http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf